# Does the application functor have adjoints?

Tags: category-theory

For $K$ and $C$ categories, with $C$ complete and cocomplete, we define the application functor on a fixed $k:K$ as $\ @\ k : [K,C]\rightarrow C$

$$D\ @\ k = D\ k$$
$$\alpha\ @\ k = \alpha_k$$

for $D:[K,C]$ and $\alpha$ a natural transformation between two functors in $[K,C]$.

Does $\ @\ k$ have left or right adjoints? How do you go about finding one?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That depends. Is $\mathcal{C}$ complete? Cocomplete?

Comment: @ZhenLin I'm sorry, I forgot. Indeed we may assume C is complete for it to have a left adjoint and cocomplete for a right adjoint. (I think that's the way we'll need them at least.) Editing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the Yoneda lemma, we have
$$\mathcal{C} (c, c' (k)) \cong [\mathcal{K}, \textbf{Set}](\mathcal{K} (k, -), \mathcal{C} (c, c' (-)))$$
naturally in $c$ and $c'$.
Assuming $\mathcal{C}$ has coproducts, or at least copowers, the functor
$$\textbf{Set} (X, \mathcal{C} (c, -)) : \mathcal{C} \to \textbf{Set}$$
is representable for every set $X$; let $X \odot c$ be the representing object.
(It is, equivalently, the coproduct of $X$-many copies of $c$.)
Consider the diagram:
$$\mathcal{K} (k, -) \odot c : \mathcal{K} \to \mathcal{C}$$
By definition, we have
$$\mathcal{C} (\mathcal{K} (k, k') \odot c, c' (k')) \cong \textbf{Set} (\mathcal{K} (k, k'), \mathcal{C} (c, c' (k'))$$
naturally in $c'$ and dinaturally in $k'$.
Hence,
$$[\mathcal{K}, \mathcal{C}] (\mathcal{K} (k, -) \odot c, c') \cong [\mathcal{K}, \textbf{Set}] (\mathcal{K} (k, -), \mathcal{C} (c, c' (-))) \cong \mathcal{C} (c, c' (k))$$
naturally in $c'$.
But that means the left adjoint of ${-} @ k$ evaluated at $c$ exists and is $\mathcal{K} (k, -) \odot c$.
In particular, ${-} @ k$ has a left adjoint.

Dually, assuming $\mathcal{C}$ has products, or at least powers, ${-} @ k$ has a right adjoint.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! 

Just to verify I must ask. If C had binary products, it's the same construction but using usual curryfication, right? 

Also as a note for anyone else interested, this immediately proves that limits are calculated pointwise.

Comment: No...? I don't see how this is like currying.