# Equation in the paper "homotopy limits for 2-categories"

Tags: category-theory, enriched-category-theory, 2-categories

I do not understand a step in the paper "Homotopy Limits for 2-Categories" by Nicola Gambino. The two longer calculations on page 22 together imply that
\begin{align}
\textrm{Ps}(\mathscr J,\textrm{Cat})(W, K(X,D-)) \cong \textrm{Ps}(\mathscr J,K)(W(-) \ast X,D) 
\end{align}
when $K$ is a 2-category with copowers denoted by $\ast$. I do not see how the equation above follows from the universal property
\begin{align}
\textrm{Cat}(W,K(A,B)) \cong K(W\ast A,B) 
\end{align}
of cotensors in $K$. Can somebody help me?

Comment: Probably you need to "expand" the category of transformations using some kind of end formula. It looks analogous to the same formula for enriched categories. See this [argument](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4711372/5191) for the case of ordinary categories.

Comment: @ZhenLin Yes, that is what I was thinking too! But I am not aware of an end-formula for the weaker $\textrm{Ps}(\mathscr J,\textrm{Cat})$, though I would be down to believe that such a formula exists for the enriched $[\mathscr J,\textrm{Cat}]$

Comment: @ZhenLin you are right! i found https://arxiv.org/pdf/2210.01522.pdf which also speaks about "pseudo-ends", and with that it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very short computation with the help of pseudo-ends, whose theory is developed in the very recent text [Notes on Lax Ends](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2210.01522.pdf) by Kengo Hirata. One can compute:
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Ps}(\mathscr J,K)(W,K(A,D-)) &\cong \textstyle \int_X^{ps} \operatorname{Cat}(WX,K(A,DX)) \\
&\cong \textstyle \int _X^{ps}\operatorname{Cat}(WX*A,DX) \\
&\cong \operatorname{Ps}(\mathscr J,K)(W(-)*A,D)
\end{align*}